# Full screen BG, divs that scroll over the initial landing screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm pretty new to coding, so please excuse any simple mistakes.  I've tried looking this up, but I haven't found an exact solution to what I'm looking for.

Basically, what I want is a full screen background for the landing page.  On this landing page, I have a vertically & horizontally centered div for title/intro.  When I scroll down, I want it to a white div that fits the entire screen width and essentially scrolls over the background and moving the title div up as well.

Here's what I have so far:

```css
html,body{
 height: 100%;
}

body{
 font-family: 'American Typewriter', serif;
 font-weight: lighter;
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/83/An_old_barn_with_the_Big_Horn_Mountains_in_the_background._Not_far_from_Sheridan,_Wyoming.JPG') no-repeat 50% 50%;
background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
}

div.name{
 font-size:100px;
 color: #fff;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}

div.container-intro{
height:100%;
width:100%;
display: table;
margin: auto;

}

div.container-inner{
text-align: center;
vertical-align:middle;
display: table-cell;
}

a.main-link{
 border: 3px solid #fff;
 padding:5px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 width:fixed;
}


div.big-white{
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 100%;
 margin:auto;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="container-intro">
 <div class="container-inner">
<div class="name">title</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
 
<a class="main-link col-md-4 col-md-offset-1" href="#">link</a> 
<a class="main-link col-md-4 col-md-offset-1" href="#">link</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="big-white col-md-12">
 Hello
</div>
</div>
```

Essentially, "big-white" is supposed to be 100% width and scroll over the bg, pushing up the initial divs.  I'm sorry this is not explained well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you want, just add `fixed` to you background in CSS and set body margin to `0px`.

```
body{
    margin:0px;
    font-family: 'American Typewriter', serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    background: url('https://foo.bar/img.JPG') no-repeat 50% 50% fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add background-repeat property to your css body elemnt

```
body{
    ...
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```